# oracle index in table join

Tags: oracle10g

if I do

```
select * 
    from table1 
    where table1.col1 = 'xx' 
        and table1.col2 = 'yy' 
        and table1.col3= 'zz'`
```

the execution plan shows full table scan.
The indexes on this table exist for col4 and col5.
Do I need to set an index on each one of col1,col2,col3 to make the query perform better?

Also if the query is like this:

```
select * 
    from table1,table2 
    where table1.col1=table2.col2 
        and table1.col2 = 'yy' 
        and table1.col3= 'zz'
```

If we create an index on col1 and col2, will it suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try adding indexes on the columns that you are using in the query:

- table1 col1
- table1 col2
- table1 col3
- table2 col2

Note that it can also be advantageous in some cases to have multi-column indexes, for example:

- table1 (col2, col3)

It's hard to predict which index will work best without knowing more about your data, but you can try a few different possibilities and see what works best.

Comment: Thanks. You mentioned 'without knowing more about data' What can I check before I create indexes on all columns?

Comment: @Kaushik: The important thing is the selectivity of the index. The database will generally prefer to use the most selective index. An easy way to find out which is the better index is to add all the indexes you think might be used and then look at the query plan to see which of them is actually used. Then you can remove the other indexes again if you don't need them. Obviously this works better if you have a table with a reasonable amount of test data in it - if the table is nearly empty the indexes won't be used, and if you have billions of rows the index creation will take a long time.